# How do I rotate LCD touch panel on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, touchscreen, config.txt, raspbian-lite

I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't find a solution that works anywhere to rotate the official raspberry pi touch screen (not the display part as this is working, just the touch panel) on my raspberry pi 3 90 degrees to the left. I commented out dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d as display_lcd_rotate=1 does not work when enabled.

My /boot/config.txt changes...

```
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
[ALL]
display_lcd_rotate=1
xinput set-prop 'raspberrypi-ts' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Edit: I'm using the official raspbian lite version and starting Xorg-server in systemd if that matters.

Edit: I ended up finding a solution, I changed /boot/config.txt to:

```
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406,touchscreen-swapped-x-y=1,touchscreen-inverted-x=1
[ALL]
display_lcd_rotate=1
```

Comment: please post the answer as "answer" at the bottom of this page ... not as "question" ... you can then accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing an answer to the same questoin which I spent hours this arvo to find an answer for, if you are using RB3, this is the answer:

[image]

Also, below is the OPs answer for the future reference:

I ended up finding a solution, I changed /boot/config.txt to:

#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406,touchscreen-swapped-x-y=1,touchscreen-inverted-x=1
[ALL]
display_lcd_rotate=1